# Python wont define function

Tags: python

I am getting back into python and I'm having a really basic issue....

My source has the following...

```
def calrounds(rounds):
    print rounds
```

When I run this through the shell and try to call calrounds(3) I get..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    calrounds(3)
NameError: name 'calrounds' is not defined
```

Its been awhile since I've used python, humor me.

Comment: You say your source file has a function defined, and you are trying to call the function from the shell. How exactly did you load your source into the shell?

Comment: How exactly you run this? Is this a contents of a file or written directly into the shell?

Comment: I open my python and then do run in shell from the top menu.

Answer (score 2):

Did you `import` your source first?

Answer (score 1):

It says that the first line of your program is calling `calrounds` with a parameter `3`. Move that below your function definition. The definition needs to be before you call the function. If you are using python 3.0+ you need parenthesis for the print statement.

```
>>> def calrounds(rounds):
    print(rounds)


>>> calrounds(3)
3
```

Comment: He's running it from the shell, it's not actually the first line of a source file.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to look at how you're calling the function.  Assuming it's in `myModule.py`, did you `import myModule` or did you `from myModule import calrounds`?  If you used the first one, you need to call it as `myModule.calrounds()`.

Next thing I would do is to make sure that you're restarting your interpreter.  If you have `import`ed a module, `importing` it again **will not** reload the source, but use what is already in memory.

The next posibility is that you're importing a file other than the one you think you are.  You might be in a different directory or loading something from the standard library.  After you `import myModule` you should `print myModule.__file__` and see if it is the file you think you're working on.  After 20 years of programming, I still find myself doing this about once a year and it's incredibly frustrating.

Finally, there's the chance that Python is just acting up.  Next to your `myModule.py` there will be a `myModule.pyc` - this is where Python puts the compiled code so it can load modules faster.  Normally it's smart enough to tell if your source has been modified but, occassionally, it fails.  Delete your `.pyc` file and restart the interpreter.

Comment: If `myModule` is in the namespace, restarting the interpreter can be avoided, doing `reload(myModule)` instead